# Why is the installation of ubuntu on HP Pavilion ZD8000 failing?

Tags: system-installation

I have a HP pavilion zd8000 machine 80G HDD, 1G RAM, Pentium 4.  I can get Ubuntu to run on it in the "try" mode, but it will not install.  before it gets to the screen where you choose to run alongside windows, I get a screen full of messages and it just stops.  Could the CD I created be corrupt or is there an incompatibility issue with the PC?

Comment: Which ubuntu are you trying to install? What are the messages? Please edit your question to include the error messages that you speak of.

Answer (score 0):

Have you reviewed this bug report:

https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-nettool/+question/220688

Initially I thought, compatibility issues with your laptop are unlikely since [others have had good success](http://www.linlap.com/hp_pavilion_zd8000) getting it to run on a HP Pavilion ZD8000.

---

though not relevant, here are the instructions for md5sum checking:

You can follow the instructions at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM to check whether your CD is corrupt. If you have a linux system running, you can use the commandline `md5sum` program:

```
dd if=/dev/cdrom bs=1 count=732766208 | md5sum
```

(Details at the link above)

On windows you will have to download a program to calculated the md5sum of a disk such as [winMD5Sum](http://www.nullriver.com/downloads/Install-winMd5Sum.exe).

Comment: I am trying to install 12.04.2  There is a whole screen of messages, not necessarily errors.  I see something that says Invalid opcode: 0000 [#1] SMP

Comment: Also Something that says Pid" 5792, comm: modprobe Tainted: P W 0 3.5.0-23 generic ....  Also it stops on a line that says  [287.040082] EIP: [<f969b521>] wdev_priv.part.7+0x3/0x5 [wl] SS:ESP 0068:eb759cec.  I'd send a pic of the screen, but not sure if I can attach it.  This is my first time attempting to use Ubuntu.  I was extremely impressed with the "try" experience.

Comment: Did the checksum on the iso file - it was okay.  Burned a new DVD.  Still the same thing

Comment: You can go to your question and hit the edit link under it. Once you are editing your question (which you should do if you find more relevant information), you can click on a link saying `img` just above the editing field. This will allow you to upload images from your computer.

Comment: I still have a bad reputation :-)  Less than 10, so I can't post images

Comment: hope my votes are giving you a leg up with that ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I tried installing 12.04.2 to a HP zv5000 (laptop) from DVD (when given the 2 buttons 'Try Ubuntu' or 'Install Ubuntu' - I selected the Install option) and encountered, and got stuck on, the similar text msg page.

I restarted PC, loading Ubuntu in the 'Try Mode' (from DVD). Then I click on the 'Install Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS' icon on the Ubuntu desktop and I was able to proceed.

Hope this works for you too.